# What's the preferred C++ idiom to own a collection of polymorphic objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

Consider the following classes

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public
    virtual void do_stuff() { std::cout << "I'm useful"; };
};
```

Now let's say I want to have another class responsible for owning objects of `Base`'s derived types and iterate through them calling their `do_stuff()` method.  It looks like this, but I don't know what `T` should be declared as

```
class Owner {
public:
    void do_all_stuff() {
        //iterate through all items and call do_stuff() on them
    }

    void add_item(T item) {
        items.push_back(item);
    }

    vector<T> items;
}
```

I see a few possibilities:

`T` can't be `Base`, since I would only be able to add objects of concrete type `Base`, so that's out of the question.

`T` can be `Base*` or `Base&`, but now I need to trust the caller of `add_item()` to pass me a pointer or a reference to an object that will still exist when I retrieve it from `items`.  I can't `delete` the elements in `Owner`'s destructor, since I don't know that they were dynamically allocated.  However, they should be `delete`'d if they were, which leaves me with ambiguous ownership.

`T` can be `Base*` or `Base&` and I add a `Base* create_item<DerivedT>() { return new DerivedT; }` method to `Owner`.  This way, I know the pointer will remain valid and I own it, but I'm unable to call a non-default constructor on `DerivedT`.  Also, `Owner` becomes responsible for instantiating objects as well.  I also have to delete every item in `Owner`'s destructor, although that's not much of an issue.

Basically, I'd like to be able to do something similar to:

```
Owner owner;

void add_one() {
    Derived d;

    owner.add_item(d);
}

void ready() {
    owner.do_all_stuff();
}

void main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        add_one();
    }
    ready();
}
```

I'm sure there's something related to move semantics in there (I could move the objects passed to `add_items()` to own them) but I still can't figure out how my collection would be declared.

What is the C++ idiom for this sort of polymorphic ownership (particularly with STL containers)?

Comment: If you want polymorphism, you will eventually end up doing `std::container<Base *>`, "ambiguous" or not. If you are worried about memory management, then you can make a `container<shared_ptr<Base> >` as well.

Comment: You don't have a great variety of choices. You can have a collection of (a) raw pointers (b) smart pointers. That's about it. In theory (a) can be further subdivided into (a.1) raw pointers to objects owned by the container, and (a.2) raw pointers to objects not owned by the container. You just need to toss a coin and decide. If it comes to rest on either face, use (b). If it comes to rest standing on its edge, use (a.1). If it remains suspended in the air, use (a.2). Easy, innit?

Comment: If you end up one day needing a factory method like `create_item`, I guess you could use variadic templates to give parameters to the constructor of `DerivedT` and use `std::is_base_of` to make sure it's a derived class.

Comment: @n.m. You really should have made that an answer instead of a comment... ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Polymorphic objects have to be handled by pointer or reference. Since their lifetime is probably not bound to a particular scope they will also probably have dynamic storage duration, which means you should use a smart pointer.

Smart pointers such as `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` work just fine in the standard collection types.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>
```

Using this in `Owner` looks like:

```
class Owner {
public:
    void do_all_stuff() {
        //iterate through all items and call do_stuff() on them
    }

    void add_item(std::unique_ptr<Base> item) {
        items.push_back(std::move(item));
    }

    vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> items;
}
```

The argument type to `add_item` identifies the ownership policy required for adding an item, and requires the user to go out of their way to screw it up. For example they can't accidentally pass a raw pointer with some implicit, incompatible ownership semantics because `unique_ptr` has an explicit constructor.

`unique_ptr` will also take care of deleting the objects owned by `Owner`. Although you do need to ensure that `Base` has a virtual destructor. With your current definition you will get undefined behavior. Polymorphic objects should pretty much always have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.  I'd just like to point out for future reference that it should be `items.push_back(std::move(item));` since a `unique_ptr` can't be copied.

Comment: Also, emplace_back should be prefered my default. But it's equivalent when moving if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Klaim No practical difference from `push_back` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming from your context that `Owner` is the *sole* owner of the contained objects,`T` should be `unique_ptr<Base>` (where `unique_ptr` comes from boost or std depending on your C++11 availability). This properly recognizes that it's solely owned by the container and additionally shows the ownership transferral semantics in your `add_item` call.

Comment: Actually, in a container, it's probably better to use `std::shared_ptr`, rather than `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @James Kanze Can you elaborate why, in a sole ownership container, you would prefer the additional overhead of `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @JamesKanze Why? `unique_ptr` would be my first choice as well. In addition to performing better, using less memory, and not forcing synchronization, `unique_ptr` (presumably) reflects the ownership semantics more accurately.

Comment: @MarkB A more intuitive interface.  With `unique_ptr`, I need extra code when reading an element, either through an iterator or by indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternatives worth considering are to use `boost::ptr_container`, or even better, use a library like `adobe::poly` or `boost::type_erasure` for your polymorphic types, to exploit value-based run-time polymorphism—avoids the need for pointers, inheritance, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot store references in STL, only pointers or real values.
So T is Base*
Try other things you will have your compiler complaining.

Comment: Actually, you probably want your container to hold `shared_ptr<Base>` or `unique_ptr<Base>`, as opposed to a plain `Base*`.

Comment: It depends on the situation. They are viable options.

Comment: Another option is reference_wrapper<Base>.

Comment: That sadly doesn't answer my question.  I'm able to get the thing compiling and working but I'd like to know the idiomatic way this is usually solved.

Comment: @pwny, sometimes std::vector is the wrong answer, and std::list is better. Sometimes std::set is better. Likewise, sometimes you want std::vector<Base*> and sometimes you want std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>). Both are valid. There is no single correct answer. The only wrong answer, is roll you own unique_ptr or roll your own vector_of_pointers. (Although sometimes the vector_of_pointers is correct.) Heck, sometimes a raw array of Base* is the right answer. It depends.