# How to pass an interface object to a method?

Tags: c++, dictionary, methods, interface

I need to pass an object (defined as an interface) to a method but i don't know ho to do it.
The method has to add this object to a map. Obviusly the objects passed will be daughters of the interface IFigure.

```
void Drawing::addFigure(string id, IFigure figure) {
    drawings.insert(id, figure);
}
```

And the Map is defined like this (in class Drawing):

```
map<string,IFigure> drawings;
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What wrong happens with your code?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In it they will discuss polymorphism and how you have to handle polymorphic types.

Comment: Look-up "object slicing"

Comment: @dedecos It is going to slice.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532076/whats-the-preferred-c-idiom-to-own-a-collection-of-polymorphic-objects

Comment: You probably need one of `map<string,IFigure*> drawings;` or `map<string,std::unique_ptr<IFigure>> drawings;` or `map<string,std::shared_ptr<IFigure>> drawings;` (or `map<string,std::weak_ptr<IFigure>> drawings;`)

Comment: @Jarod42 i tried with map<string,IFigure*> drawings, but now how i can use the insert method to add the new figure?

Comment: `void Drawing::addFigure(string id, IFigure* figure)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create instances of abstract classes.

So declaring that:

```
IFigure figure;
```

This construct a new `IFigure`. You can't do that.

```
IFigure figure = Implementation{};
```

This won't work either. You are creating a new `IFigure` by copying a sliced `Implementation`. You can't do that either.

Variable are values, just like `int`. `IFigure figure` denote a value of type `IFigure`, not a reference to an implementation. It can't ever work.

Slicing is kind of asking something like this:

```
int i = double{1.6};
std::cout << i;
// Why does it prints '1'?? I assigned '1.6', it should refer to it!
```

Of course, a conversion happen so it drops the `.6` part. Just like slicing drops the `Implementation` part to keep the base class part only.

---

So what can you do??

You can use something that act like a reference so you could have something that look like a `IFigure` but really points to a `Implementation`. A reference could work, but they aren't so dynamic, so pointers would do it too.

```
//  a pointer to base             we tell to point it to this allocated implementation
std::unique_ptr<IFigure> figure = std::make_unique<Implementation>();
```

When using a container like a `std::map`, you can also use pointers like this:

```
std::map<string,std::unique_ptr<IFigure>> figures;
```

Each element looked like this with values:

```
+--------+---------------+
| string |    IFigure    |
+--------+---------------+
```

With pointers:

```
      +------------------+
      |  Implementation  |
      +------------------+
            ^
            |
+--------+--|---+
| string | ptr  |
+--------+------+
```

And use it like this:

```
figures.emplace("id1", std::make_unique<Implementation>());
// or
figures["id2"] = std::make_unique<Implementation>();

// or even
void Drawing::addFigure(std::string id, std::unique_ptr<IFigure> figure) {
    // move ownership from 'figure' into 'drawings' so
    // 'drawing' becomes the owner and 'figure' becomes null.
    drawings.emplace(id, std:move(figure));
}
```

> Why not `std::map<string, IFigure*>`? It look simpler.

If you intend the container to be the owner of all the data (all element destroyed when the container dies) then the pointers becomes owning. Using owning raw pointers comes with a lot of issues that are hard to deal as beginners. If you use `new`, there is probably a mistake or you have very specific needs.